# convert time_utc to local time with timezone pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a variable time UTC to Local time according to `Local_timezone` variable.

I have a dataframe time_df with variable `TIMEZONE` and a second dataframe `data_df` with variable `time_utc`.
I want to create a local_time variable in my dataframe.

`TIMEZONE` is a string and `time_utc` is a datetime.

I do it like this:

```
local_timezone = time_df['TIMEZONE']

data_df.loc[data_df['time_utc'].tz_convert(local_timezone), 'local_time']
```

I have this error:

```
TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Comment: can you show some examples of your data in dataframe?

Comment: Please send the output of `print(local_timezone.head().to_dict(), local_timezone.shape, data_df.head().to_dict(), data_df.shape)`

Comment: Sure,  here is an example of my `time_utc` : `2021-12-03 01:33:00+00:00` and my `TIMEZONE` : `Europe/Paris`. Sorry I can't add a screen of my dataframe.

Comment: Sure, the output is : `{0: 'Europe/Paris', 1: 'Europe/Paris', 2: 'Europe/Paris'} (3,) {'equipement': {0: 'R6401', 1: 'R6401', 2: 'R6401', 3: 'R6401', 4: 'R6401'}, 'product_name_x': {0: 'XX', 1: 'XX', 2: 'XX', 3: 'XX', 4: 'XX'}, 'Batch_Continuous': {0: 'CONTINUOUS', 1: 'CONTINUOUS', 2: 'CONTINUOUS', 3: 'CONTINUOUS', 4: 'CONTINUOUS'}, 'reactor': {0: 'CONT', 1: 'CONT', 2: 'CONT', 3: 'CONT', 4: 'CONT'}, 'product': {0: 'XX', 1: 'XX', 2: 'XX', 3: 'XX', 4: 'XX'}, 'time_utc': {0: Timestamp('2021-12-03 01:33:00+0000', tz='UTC') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you merge `data_df` with `time_df` already. It means that your `data_df` will have `time_utc`, `TIMEZONE`, and etc.

e.g.

```
local_timezone = time_df['TIMEZONE']
local_timezone = local_timezone.to_frame('TIMEZONE')
data_df = pd.concat([data_df , local_timezone], axis=1)
```

To convert the time zone of `time_utc` to local time, use `apply()` to apply a time zone to each value.

```
def set_timezone(row):
    return row['time_utc'].tz_convert(row['TIMEZONE'])

data_df['local_time'] = data_df.apply(lambda x: set_timezone(x), axis = 1)
```

---

**OUTPUT**

Before:

```
>>> data_df
                   time_utc      TIMEZONE
0 2021-12-03 01:33:00+00:00  Europe/Paris
1 2021-12-03 03:50:00+00:00  Europe/Paris
```

After:

```
>>> data_df['local_time'] = data_df.apply(lambda x: set_timezone(x), axis = 1)
>>> data_df
                   time_utc      TIMEZONE                local_time
0 2021-12-03 01:33:00+00:00  Europe/Paris 2021-12-03 02:33:00+01:00
1 2021-12-03 03:50:00+00:00  Europe/Paris 2021-12-03 04:50:00+01:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I use apply I have this error `KeyError: 'TIMEZONE'`. In fact `time_UTC` and `TIMEZONE` are in different dataframes.

Comment: so you need to `concat` them first see the first code section above. or you need to manipulate them without concatenation?

Comment: without merging them into the same dataframe, it is a bit tricky to do across different dataframes.

Comment: Thank you, with merging them into the same dataframe it work !